Rolling with it
As brown as a bear
As round as a pear
As dry as a bone
As bored as a lone
Rolling to the wind
Falling to the field
Burns like hell
Ruined our yield
Forget not the thorns
Be not afraid
Protect, shall the lords
As the damage will be paid.

Are you

A tumbleweed?


As brown as a bear
As round as a pear
As dry as a bone
As bored as a lone

Tumbleweeds are brown, round, dry and often alone:



Rolling to the wind
Falling to the field
Burns like hell
Ruined our yield

Tumbleweeds are transported by the wind, and very flammable. They are a nuisance to crops due to spreading wildfires, as well as stealing nutrients and water from fields and carrying diseases

Forget not the thorns
Be not afraid
Protect, shall the lords
As the damage will be paid.

Tumbleweeds have very large thorns that can do a lot of damage to, for instance cars. Better hope you have insurance!


That is correct!
